# How to see detailed information about a given PID?

Tags: command-line, process

The headline basically says it all. I have a program where I am only given the PID, nothing more really, and I would like to know how I get more information about the given process.

Comment: If you are working in python you probably want to use the `psutil` library. Do: `psutil.Process(pid)` to obtain the process object and then use its interface to retrieve information about memory/cpu etc. etc.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
ps -Flww -p THE_PID
```

will show you some information. See the [ps manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ps.1.html) for more information about the `ps` command. The ["STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS" section](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ps.1.html#contenttoc15) explains what the different columns mean.

Comment: Thanks. Why did you write `ww` instead of just one `w`? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446099/what-is-the-purpose-of-double-w-in-ps-ww

Comment: How do I get it to print the full non-truncated username?

Comment: @Tim, from the manpage `-w    Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.`

Answer (score 25):

I don't know what is your exact requirement. but this may help you.

There is separate directory for every process with name as pid number in `/proc` .

```
ps -ef | grep docker 
root      1700     1  0 Sep20 ?        00:03:04 /usr/bin/docker daemon --raw-logs
```

In above output PID is 1700 .

goto `/proc/1700`

```
cd /proc/1700
```

and do `ls` there

```
ls
attr       clear_refs       cpuset   fd       limits     mem         net        oom_score      projid_map  sessionid  stat     task
autogroup  cmdline          cwd      fdinfo   loginuid   mountinfo   ns         oom_score_adj  root        setgroups  statm    timers
auxv       comm             environ  gid_map  map_files  mounts      numa_maps  pagemap        sched       smaps      status   uid_map
cgroup     coredump_filter  exe      io       maps       mountstats  oom_adj    personality    schedstat   stack      syscall  wchan
```

there is many file that have all information about process.

Like:

```
cat /proc/1700/status

Name:   docker
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   1700
Ngid:   0
Pid:    1700
PPid:   1
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    0   0   0   0
FDSize: 64
Groups: 0 999 
VmPeak:   527576 kB
VmSize:   527512 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     46032 kB
VmRSS:     34180 kB
VmData:   449308 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:     28324 kB
VmLib:      4236 kB
VmPTE:       296 kB
VmSwap:     5324 kB
Threads:    12
SigQ:   0/63662
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: ffffffffffc1feff
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000003fffffffff
CapEff: 0000003fffffffff
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
Seccomp:    0
Cpus_allowed:   f
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-3
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    437726
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 27579
```

If you need basic command to get process information then you can easily get using command:

```
man ps
```

Answer (score 6):

To add to the `ps` answer there is also the `pidstat` command which will show additional stats like the time spent in user mode or the occupation of the cpu. You can use it with:

```
# pidstat -p 51648
```

You can also add the `-d` flag to add details about I/O:

```
# pidstat -p 51648 -d
```

And you can also an integer as a second parameter to make the command refresh each X seconds:

```
# pidstat -p 51648 3
```

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu provide `pidstat` with the *sysstat* package.

Answer (score 0):

[`px`](https://github.com/walles/px), available via the [*px* package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/px), is a great tool for giving detailed information about a running process.

```
px $SOME_PID
```